# TPL - Local Variable iniitalisation once for all

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a quick question about TPL.
I would like for each thread in a Parallel.For to have an integer which value is assigned only once and for all (at initilaisation and should never change - be thread specific).

I cannot come with anything working even when using LocalStorage.

Exemple: 
4 threads, each has int localvar = initialised with {1,2,3,4} and should keep the same value during all the for loop

Many Thanks !

Edit

When running this

```
 ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
                options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4                
int ir = 0;
                Parallel.For(0, 10, options, () => ir++, (index, s, n) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(n); return n;
                }, n => { });
```

The  resukt is   `n = ir = 7`

Comment: So even if you call `Parallel.For` multiple times, you still want these values to remain the same?

Comment: @Noseratio No, that's not mandatory. I only want them to remain the same during same for loop. Indeed, the solution given in the top answer seemed legit and I did this way in the first place but it is still incrementing the local variable `n` even when it reaches the MaxDegreeofParallelism

Answer (score 1):

Use [one of the overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd782936) that accepts a local init block.  It's designed specifically for this:

```
int i = 0;
Parallel.For(0, 10, () => i++, (index, s, n) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(n); return n;
}, n => { });
```

Comment: This is precisely what I did, but at each iteration of the for loop, the `() => i++` part is called which results in `i` being incremented all the time which is wrong.

Comment: @VLT Then you're not using the right overload.  It won't be called for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: i is incremented untils 10 in your example, whereas I need it to be incremented once for each thread

Comment: @VLT It doesn't increment to 10 when I run it.  Either you've changed something, or you're actually using 10 threads.